# Creating imagine from Memorystream using FromStream gives out of memory error

Tags: vb.net, memorystream

I have a simple implemententation to create an imagine from a btye[] array using System.Drawing.Image.FromStream.  See below:

```
Using ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Value), 0, Convert.FromBase64String(Value).Length)

       Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
       img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
       eRow.Properties.Value = img
End Using
```

This does work most of the time.  Now and then I get an error 'out of memory' error trying to load the exact same imagine.

Message: Out of memory.  Stack:    at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)     at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Rectangle srcRect, GraphicsUnit srcUnit)     at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.PictureEditPainter.DrawImageCore(ControlGraphicsInfoArgs info, PictureEditViewInfo vi, RectangleF screen, RectangleF source, Image image, Boolean prevImage)     at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.PictureEditPainter.DrawImage(ControlGraphicsInfoArgs info)     at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.PictureEditPainter.DrawContent(ControlGraphicsInfoArgs info)     at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.BaseControlPainter.Draw(ControlGraphicsInfoArgs info)     at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Drawing.BaseEditPainter.Draw(ControlGraphicsInfoArgs info)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Painters.VGridPainter.DrawRowValueCellCore(CustomDrawRowValueCellEventArgs e, BaseEditPainter pb, BaseEditViewInfo bvi, BaseViewInfo vi)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Painters.VGridPainter.DrawRowValueCell(RowValueInfo rv, BaseViewInfo vi, MultiEditorRowViewInfo meri, Int32& sepIndex)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Painters.VGridPainter.DrawRow(BaseRowViewInfo ri)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Painters.VGridPainter.DrawRows(BaseViewInfo vi)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Painters.VGridPainter.DoDrawCore(BaseViewInfo vi)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Painters.VGridPainter.DoDraw(DXPaintEventArgs e, BaseViewInfo vi)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.VGridControlBase.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)     at DevExpress.XtraEditors.Container.EditorContainer.WndProc(Message& m)     at DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.VGridControlBase.WndProc(Message& m)     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)     at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)  Source: System.Drawing

I did notice that when calling this line 'img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)',  the ms.position does not get to the end/ not equal to the length of ms.length and that's when I get this error.

Adding a little more context.  The original imagine was a .jpeg of about 30kb, saved to a memorystream which was then converted to a string and encoded to base64.  I saved the string into a sql database of varchar(max).  I then retrieve that string from sql and load the string into a datatable as a string.  When required, I then retrieve the string from the datatable and call the above function.

This is the code I use to convert the image, which _newValue is then saved to sql database as varchar(max)

```
Using ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()                             CType(value, Image).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
       _newValue = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray)
End Using
```

Again, it only happens once in awhile on the same imagine.  Would anyone have any ideas why this would happen on and off?
Thanks

Comment: `dim imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Value) using ms as new MemoryStream(imageBytes, false) ms.Position = 0 Dim img = Image.FromStream(ms, True) end using`. The image size and type must be compatible with a GDI+ Bitmap object size requirements and supported types.

Comment: Hi Jimi, thanks for the input,  the image size and type is compatible.  Let me clarify,  a particular imagine will load most of the time,  but the odd times it will not.  I have added a try/catch to not load if I get the 'out of memory'.  Even after I get the error,  the very next time (maybe 5 seconds later) I try loading the same imagine it will work.

Comment: Yes, well, that was clear: sometimes you get an exception. You need to specify (updating your question, not in comments), in what context these Images are generated, their source, the size of the Image and post the code that illustrates the operations performed in this *context*.

Comment: Since you have, for some reasons, a Base64String that contains the Image data, the nature and origin of this string is also important. If threading is involved in some way, that's also relevant.

Comment: The Image and Bitmap classes are lazy, they may need to access their underlying storage when you use them.  Highly unpredictable when that happens, it depends on the specific image format and size.  That cannot work in this code, it disposed the MemoryStream.  The exception is lousy, it doesn't know why the storage suddenly disappeared.  You cannot use `Using`.  Don't worry about disposing that stream, it is only memory.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the feedback.  I removed the 'using' command and unfortunately I still get the same issue sporadically.